# How to start updating my website dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, dynamic

So I have completely finished my website in HTML/CSS and I have added all the pictures, text etc. Everything works when I test it offline but I don't know how I can go about dynamically updating it without having to re-upload the entire thing if I want to add something new. I have created a small website that deals mostly with the news/tv shows/music and I want to be able to update it dynamically with new content. Can someone please point me in the right direction or tell me where I should start?

Here's an image that illustrates my problem and I hope you can understand it. :D

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CNgG.jpg

http://cubeupload.com/im/zN5tFf.jpg

Comment: Define "update it dynamically" - How?  from which source ?

Comment: Acquire [XXAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and learn how to store these code bits inside of MySQL and then using PHP loop through them and display them as desired. Once you're familiar with that, make yourself an admin section to post new content from anywhere you want via the browser.

Comment: @alfasin I think he meant Content. Updating content on the fly.

Comment: @2-Stroker a) if you're right - the use of the word "dynamically" is misleading here - we shouldn't have to guess. b) it could be that he wants dynamic updates (using AJAX) from another site, for example, ABC news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid any server side scripting, CMS and setting up MySQL, you could consider using a Google Fusion Table.  Make a table with a column for each image, text, link and category - then you can get a neat JSON feed, parse it into a template and away you go.  Once it's in place, all you need to do is change the image/text/link/category in the Fusion Table and your site will update automatically. Start here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/

Answer (score 0):

So if you want that your website to be dynamical you will need CMS, so in this case you need understanding of PHP, and pick some CMS platform like Wordpress or some that suits you. I asume that you dont know any programming language becouse you asked this kinda question, if you want to build dynamical website you will need to learn atleast some CMS. Or if you want to dive more into that technology you will need to learn PHP/MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CMS(Content Management System) There are tons of open source CMS available now. You can start by looking into [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/download/), [Drupal](https://drupal.org/start) etc. You dont need to know Php/Mysql to set up these and manage. It can be easily configured and there are lots of plugins available for them. So pick one and design your website the way you want it.

Here s one [Drupal test site](http://simplytest.me), it allows you to test the plugins, just type in panels and launch it. Once done log in to site and take a tour of Drupal. Not sure if any things like this there for Wordpress, but you will get a feel of what a CMS will do and if it fits your needs start using one !